# Why is RAID rebuild/recovery tied to a specific RAID card?

Tags: raid, data-recovery, hardware-failure, firmware

I would assume that although the RAID specification itself does not detail the implementation, the manufacturer of the card would like to write the RAID implementation just once and reuse that in all their product lines?

Hence, the RAIDn (for example RAID6) implementation of the manufacturer would be the same piece of code, regardless of their product.

In real life, this does not seem to be so, and far from different RAID product lines being cross compatible, I have seen issues where for the SAME product/SKU, the version X RAID card cannot be used to swap for a version Y RAID card

Do most manufacturers indeed have cross compatible RAID cards and I happened to choose one that does things uniquely?

Why is this so?

Comment: I know with Adaptec you can go forward, but not back.  Each new card adds features the last does not have and once it has been upgraded it can not go back.  Most raid cards have a reserved area at the front and/or end of each drive for metadata and whatever else they want.  The format of this metadata different from manufacturer to manufacturer and some times card to card so card 1 can not interpret card 2 metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never seen this happen, and it would totally not make any sense - how could you otherwise replace a broken controller without endangering the very data it was purchased to protect?

But if the BIOS revision is different then the volume names created by the RAID might be different. If you have access to the disks try and boot to something like RescueCD and look at the volume names. If they are different then you have at least some of your answers. Whoever programmed the ROM might have made a typo?

In any case I would never use controllers like that, and it makes me a bit worried to read something like that. I might swap some disks around Monday..